# other than connectivity what can lead to java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, database, networking, sybase

I have two staging nodes on an internal lan that can both ping our sybase database, located on a public lan. They both have the same datasource credentials set up (these are Coldfusion servers, so the datasources are set up in a central place, the CFIDE page). One node can query the database, the other can't. They can both telnet to the database on port 4100, and nslookup resolves for both as well. What other causes can lead to this error?

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: mydatabase.mycompany.com
```

Comment: firewalls? wrong hostname?

Comment: I second firewalls, been there so many times :)

Comment: Let me try my telnet again, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Sometimes it can be a firewall even if telnet works

Comment: we added the database server's IP to the hosts file, and voila! so it was some sort of connectivity issue that couldn't be seen by telnet or nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

UnknownHostException means the host wasn't found in the DNS. It has nothing to do with 'connectivity' at all, except maybe connectivity to the DNS itself.